# How can I send an entire group of text inputs as an array within json object?

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a section in my form that a user can "click to add more".

For example, let's say you can add a friend to your registration:

```
<a href="#">Click to add friend</a>

<label>First Name</label>
<input type="text" name="friend[firstName]">

<label>Last Name</label>
<input type="text" name="friend[lastName]">
...
```

You could have as many friends as you want.

When I submit the form, I capture the primary record in a table. We'll call it `tableA`. Once that is set, I return the insert ID and then insert all friends into `tableB` with a foreign key pointing back to the primary record.

So far so good.

What I am trying to do is capture each friend as an array and save as a json object. I am *close*, but not quite there.

The above outputs this:

```
...
[friend_data] => {"friend":{"firstName":"Tyler","lastName":"Durden"}}
```

Let's say I have added three friends. Only the last friend will get recorded (which makes sense).

So I tried changing my inputs like this:

**html**

```
<label>First Name</label>
<input type="text" name="friend[][firstName]">

<label>Last Name</label>
<input type="text" name="friend[][lastName]">
...
```

Which gets me this:

```
[friend_data] => {"friend":[{"firstName":"Tyler"},{"lastName":"Durden"},{"firstName:"Joe"},{"lastName":"Smith"}]}
```

What I (think) am trying to accomplish is this:

```
[friend_data] => {"friend":[{"firstName":"Tyler"},{"lastName":"Durden"}],[{"firstName:"Joe"},{"lastName":"Smith"}]}
```

I am using this to create the above:

**php**

```
 json_encode(array('friend' => $input['friend']))
```

That way I can loop through the json object and render each array like this:

**html**

```
<ul>
    <li>First Name: Tyler</li>
    <li>Last Name: Durden</li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li>First Name: Joe</li>
    <li>Last Name: Smith</li>
</ul>
```

Thank you for any suggestions!

**EDIT**

Thank you for your suggestion Marco Alka!

I have updated my markup like this:

**html**

```
...
<input type="text" name="friend[1][firstName]">
<input type="text" name="friend[1][lastName]">
```

My inputs are dynamically created via javascript. I when a new friend is added, the markup looks like this:

```
...
<input type="text" name="friend[2][firstName]">
<input type="text" name="friend[2][lastName]">
```

...and so on.

That generates this:

```
...
[friend_data] => {"friend":{"1":{"firstName":"Tyler","lastName":"Durden"},"2":{"firstName":"Joe","lastName":"Smith","address":"3014 SW Prairieview Rd","city":"Ankeny","zip":"","acresAllotted":""}}}
```

I still don't think that's quite right.
Does it have anything to do with how I am encoding the data?

```
$person->friend_data = json_encode(array('friend' => $input['friend']));
```

**SOLUTION**

Thanks to Marco Alka for the help! Here is what I did in the event others come across this thread.

As mentioned, I have a part to my form where I can add friends to my registration. By default, only one friend is visible when the page loads. Using javascript (jQuery) I allow the user to add as many friends as they want.

This is the markup that is on the page when it initially loads (shortened for simplicity).

**html**

```
<p><a href="#" id="add">Add Friend</a>
<form>
<div class="clone">
<label>First Name</label>
<input type="text" name="friends[1][firstName]">

<label>Last Name</label>
<input type="text" name="friends[1][lastName]">
</div>

<button type="submit">Submit</submit>
</form>
```

**jquery**

```
var friendCount = 1;

$('#add').click(function (event) {
   // do stuff.
   // update the index
   jquery.find(':input').each(function () {
       $(this).attr('name', 'friend[' + friendCount + '][' + $(this).data('name') + ']');
            });
});
```

Then on the php side I was grab all of the values:

**php**

```
$friends = array();
foreach ($input['friend'] as $friend) {
    array_push($friends, $friend);
}
...
$person->friend_data = json_encode($friends);
```

Will yield this json:

**json**

```
[friend_data] => [{"firstName":"Tyler","lastName":"Durden"},{"firstName":"Master","lastName":"Shake"}]
```

Comment: Two questions: (1) Are you allowed to use javascript? (2) Is it ok to deliver the form data with a GET method?

Comment: It turns out I was "double" encoding the array. I used the method you suggested and it worked great. Thank you so much for your time! I will update my question for others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make useful arrays when filling in the ID:

```
Friend 1:
<label>First Name</label>
<input type="text" name="friend[0][firstName]">
<label>Last Name</label>
<input type="text" name="friend[0][lastName]">

Friend 2:
<label>First Name</label>
<input type="text" name="friend[1][firstName]">
<label>Last Name</label>
<input type="text" name="friend[1][lastName]">
```

Comment: Hi @Marco Alka - I have updated my question with your suggestion. I think its close, but I'm not quite sure I have it right yet.